# how can I match input to 2 patterns in order to respectively generate 2 different error message?

Tags: html, angular

With HTML and angular, how can I match input to 2 patterns in order to respectively generate 2 different inline error message? the "pattern" in input tag doesn't can't it.

for example, I want to check if the input start with 0. 
If it starts with 0, generate a error message"the number cannot start with 0".

Then I want to check if it's 9 digits long. If it is not 9 digits long, generate a error message "the number should be 9 digits long".

The inline error is supposed to be generated as soon as a invalid input is typed in.
I've tried using formcontrol but it broke the whole page.

```
<form id="validationForm" #validationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(validationForm)">       
    <div class="row">
        <div id="u79" class="large-7 columns" data-label="businessNumber">
            <label for="u79_input">             
                <abbr title="example">e.g.</abbr>{{'BUSINESS-NUMBER-PAGE.EXAMPLE' | translate}}
                <input id="u79_input" type="text" value="" name="businessNumber" [(ngModel)] = "businessNumber" required minlength="9" maxlength="9" pattern="^\d{9}$" #uname="ngModel" (focus)="setErrors()" class="no-margin"/>
            </label>

            <!-- inline error  -->
            <div *ngIf="!hasErrors" id="error" data-label="inline error">

                <div *ngIf="uname.errors?.required  && validationForm.submitted && !isValidFormSubmitted">
                    <small class="error">{{'BUSINESS-NUMBER-PAGE.VAL-MESSAGE-REQ' | translate}}</small>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="uname.errors?.pattern && !isValidFormSubmitted">
                    <small class="error">{{'BUSINESS-NUMBER-PAGE.VAL-MESSAGE-DIGIT' | translate}} </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and where are you stuck? Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: it's too vague. What type of angular form are you using, and where did you get stuck..................... show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need just one regex pattern for validation and you can manipulate that with the length of characters in your input field. The regex to match 9 digit number not starting with 0 is

```
^[1-9]\d{8}$
```

You can see the validation and the appropriate error messages in the demo I created **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validation-multi-pattern)**

This shows 3 types of errors

1. When the field is empty
2. The number starts with zero
3. The number is not 9 digits long

Comment: it works great! how did you managed to show 3 different messages?

Comment: @WayneWang I have update the stackblitz link to show the code as well. Just go through it and you will understand. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.